# Not able to read records form Kafka on demand

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am pushing data to a **kafka** queue using a producer.

Then I need to consume/read the data on demand, basically I want that when a rest api is fired I should be able to read one record from kafka and return.
I do not want the consumer getting invoked as soon as the data arrives in the queue rather it should get invoked when I want to.

The normal way to read is by putting under a while loop and then call the **poll** method, which then keeps getting invoked when data arrives in Queue.
But I want control over when I read the record.

Comment: Interesting approach. What about to create an on-demand consumer, seek to end and read the record?

Answer (score 0):

You could still create the consumer on demand and have it process and return a single record. Something like this:

```
...
   properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
   properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-group");
   KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
   consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
   try {
        while (!timedOut) {
            ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                // process record and return
            }
        }
        // error, no record found
    } catch (InterruptException e) {
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
...
```